# Reduce Padding in ToolStripTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, toolstrip

How do I reduce the padding (or "internal margin") of a textbox in a toolstrip?  With the padding set to 0 on all sides, there is still a substantial amount of white space above and below the text within the box.  How do I get rid of this, or why is there seemingly so much extra?

I thought that the unit for padding was pixels, so a setting of 0 should have the edge of the textbox touching the tops and bottoms of the largest letters, no?

For example, why is there so much space above the "N" and "S" pictured below (and why is that space larger than the space to the left of the "N" since the top and left padding are both 0)?

[image]

I have tried changing AutoSize to False, changing the height of the control, and changing the Margin settings (all in different combinations), but the control actually seems to remain the same size (with the unwanted white space as well) no matter what I do.

Comment: That's just the way it works — it's trying to have enough room for the font.  If you want it smaller, use a smaller font.  You probably won't like the results.

Comment: You can make the height of that `TextBox` smaller, but The height of it will not be equals to the Height of `X`, because there are some other characters like `│` which are taller than`X` as you see: `│X│` and the `TextBox` will keep enough room for such characters.

Comment: Now if your requirement is to make that `TextBox` as small as possible for a stranard `TextBox`, which is showing the `TextBox` without  border, you can do it. What's the requirement?

Comment: @RezaAghaei That's a good point about the "|" character- I didn't think about there being characters taller than capital letters. However, there is still extra space even with the taller character tested.  The requirement is simply a space constraint on the form while maintaining font size. There seems to be ~8 pixels used by white space at the moment, where the users would be ok with having no margin at all

Comment: As I said you can decrease the space to its minimum possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even today TOLLSTRIPTEXTBOX still has that annoying lean-on-top appearance (maybe the reason is in the comments). The only solution to this right now is to choose a FONT with a different justification format, which is the following font, the text will be centered:

```
Control.Font = new Font("Quicksand Medium", 8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, Convert.ToByte(162));
```